# Android Unit Testing result List<List<Model>> instead of List<Model>

Tags: android, unit-testing, observable, rx-android

I have tried to unit testing by https://medium.com/upday-devs/android-architecture-patterns-part-3-model-view-viewmodel-e7eeee76b73b. 
Why does Testsubscriber give List of ListModel result instead of ListModel ?

my test

```
public class MainViewModelTest {

@Mock
private IDataModel mDataModel;

private MainViewModel mMainViewModel;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

}

@After
public void tearDown() throws Exception {

}

@Test
public void testGetSupportedLanguages_emitsCorrectLanguages() {
    Language de = new Language("German", LanguageCode.DE);
    Language en = new Language("English", LanguageCode.EN);
    List<Language> languages = Arrays.asList(de, en);

    Observable<List<Language>> mockObservable = Observable.just(languages);

    doReturn(mockObservable).when(mDataModel).getObservableSupportedLanguages();

    Language hr = new Language("Slovakian", LanguageCode.HR);
    List<Language> expectedLanguages = Arrays.asList(de, en, hr);

    mMainViewModel = new MainViewModel(mDataModel, new ImmediateSchedulerProvider());
    TestSubscriber<List<Language>> testSubscriber = new TestSubscriber<>();

    mMainViewModel.getObservableSupportedLanguages().subscribe(testSubscriber);

    testSubscriber.assertNoErrors();
    testSubscriber.assertReceivedOnNext(expectedLanguages); //here i get List<List<Language>> instead of one List<Language>


}

}
```

in MainViewModel

```
 @NonNull
public Observable<List<Language>> getObservableSupportedLanguages() {
    return mDataModel.getObservableSupportedLanguages();
}
```

in DataModel

```
@NonNull
@Override
public Observable<List<Language>> getObservableSupportedLanguages() {
    return Observable.fromCallable(this::getLanguages);
}

@NonNull
private List<Language> getLanguages() {
    return Arrays
            .asList(new Language("English", LanguageCode.EN),
                    new Language("German", LanguageCode.DE),
                    new Language("Slovakian", LanguageCode.HR));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `assertReceivedOnNext` you can assert the full sequence of items emitted from the `Observable` and thus it is a list of elements.

If you Observable emits only one element (which by chance is itself a list of items) you can change the assertion to be:

```
testSubscriber.assertValue(expectedLanguages);
```

Comment: Thank's for your answer. Can I take only first emited element  ?

Comment: Yes, there is a method to get the list of all the emissions. Check che javadoc :)